# Como inserir HTML usando PHP de forma indentada

Tags: php, html, indentação

Criei um arquivo em PHP que quando executado CRIA um arquivo html já com um código html dentro dele. Posteriormente esse arquivo PHP que está sendo executado PEGA este arquivo HTML e insere outro código html numa div especifica do html criado. Até aqui blz eu já consigo fazer, porem precisava do arquivo final INDENTADO para uso posterior.

E ai está o problema eu não consigo ter liberdade para indentar este código, digo isso pois eu coloco espaço, quebro linha, uso \n e nada é obedecido... Eu estou começando PHP então já peço desculpas por qualquer ignorância hehe...

De preferencia queria ver se conseguia resolver isso sem a ajuda de plugins, queria realmente poder fazer isso de forma "manual"...

Vou tentar exemplificar o que fiz:

```
<?php

    $arquivoHtml = 'pasta/index.html';

    $contentHtml = file_get_contents('default.html');
    $fileHtml = fopen($arquivoHtml,'wb');
    fwrite($fileHtml,$contentHtml);
    fclose($fileHtml);

    $html = file_get_contents($arquivoHtml);

    $dom  = new DomDocument();
    $dom -> loadHTML($html);

    $node = $dom -> getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);

    $fragmento = $dom -> createDocumentFragment();
    $fragmento -> appendXML('
        <div id="id-da-div">
        </div>
    ');

    $node -> appendChild($fragmento);
    echo $dom -> saveHTMLFile($arquivoHtml);

?>
```

O resultado é exatamente este código tortinho hehe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"><title>Título</title></head><body>
    <div id="main">


                <div id="id-da-div">
                </div>

</div>
</body></html>
```

Cheguei a tentar colocar algo do tipo para complementar:

```
$dom -> formatOutput       = true;
$dom -> preserveWhiteSpace = true;
```

Com isso algumas coisas se acertaram mas não totalmente, ainda fica bem estranho.

Comment: Do jeito que você inserir no PHP ele vai ficar. Basta indentar as strings e trechos corridos da maneira desejada. Importante [edit] seu post e explicar onde teve dificuldade nisso, visto que funciona normalmente do jeito que você digitou. Exemplo: `echo '      <div>';` - isto terá tres espaços no começo, pois eu inseri dentro dos `' '`. Alternativamente, pode fazer com aspas duplas e escape: `echo "\t\t\t<div>\n";` - sendo \t para tab e \n a quebra de linha. Mas tem outras mil maneiras de fazer, o difícil é NÃO conseguir :)  Se testou com um código real e ele deu problema, edite com um [mcve].

Comment: Cara muito obrigado pela resposta hehe, bom, como vc me aconselhou eu editei a minha questão pra talvez melhor apresentar ela sou meio novo na área e em php também peço desculpas pela "leiguice" hehehe

Comment: Agora, olhando o seu código, me parece que o problema é você estar misturando a indentação do PHP com a do HTML, aí realmente não vai coincidir na maior parte das situações. O ideal seria vc ver quantos espaços ou tabs  precisa por no HTML, e fazer exatamente a mesma quantidade no append. Sinceramente, se  quer ter um controle maior, talvez o DomDocument não seja o melhor caminho. (além do echo tradicional ser mais eficiente)

Comment: Poxa obrigado pelo retorno parceiro! Eu conseguiria dar um echo, porem em uma página externa?

Comment: Alias e eu conseguiria então utilizar algo que não seja o new DomDocument() ?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [HereDoc](https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/php/php-here-document-heredoc-syntax-examples)

Mas o recomendado é que você crie um arquivo php separado com o html e faça o include dele
Exemplo HereDoc:

```
print <<< END
<p>
Seu código HTML<br/>
</p>
END;
```

Exemplo Include:

```
<?php
//your code
include 'template-index.php';
?>
```

Dê uma olhada em algum template engine, como o [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/)

Como a pergunta foi editada para uma dúvida sobre DomDocument, tente usar dessa forma

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->save($arquivoHtml);
```